# How do I mine ore?

Tags: dragons-dogma

My pawns keep telling me that I should be mining for ore, presumably in the rocks I'm nearby / standing on. How?

I have a pick-ax but I can't select "Use" from my inventory. I don't see aught shining to mash circle at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to mine for ore, have a pick-ax in your inventory, then you have to find a rock with crystal-like objects on it and press circle when you are standing in front of it.

[image: Crystal-Like objects look like so...]

Answer (score 1):

I've just realized (50+ hours into the game (!)) that your pawns will also mine for ore automatically if you provide them with pickaxes.

(Note: I've only played DD:DA so that may very well be something added with the expansion pack, I really have no idea.)